# difference between single brackets and double bracket conditionals

Tags: java, jsp, if-statement

What's the difference between encapsulating a conditional statement in double brackets over single in jsp?

lets say we have a statement like the following:

```
if (!method()) {
```

or:

```
if (!(method())) {
```

Is there any difference? In my eyes they both would equate to:

```
if (method() === false) {
```

Comment: Are you writing `if (!method())` inside scriplets in JSP?

Comment: inside the jsp i have `if (!(method()))` and was wondering - coming from a more javascript knowledge if there was any reason that was used over `(!method())` which to me equals the same thing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In simple statement both are same in the context of Java programming.

I assume the return type of `method()` is `boolean`.

---

`if (method() === false)` is not allowed in Java. It's a compile time error.

#### Don't confuse between `JavaScript` syntax and `Java` syntax.

The JSP is internally converted to the Servlet that executes on the server and the resultant HTML response is send back to the client (browser). So it's not converted to `JavaScript` at all.

Comment: Java tag was added later. I think he is writing JavaScript in JSP page.

Comment: @SubirKumarSao I answered in the context of Java programming. I have asked it again from the OP for more clarification.

Comment: sorry no, i was just trying to show the equivalent - i did write it in javascript though.